# Upload images to folder using Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I am having a problem with uploading images in a specific folder. Like I am creating a folder using name field of the form. What I want that image to upload in the newly created folder, not in a parent folder. I am attaching my code please help.

HTML:

```
<form action="assets/php/customer-query.php" method="post" class="add_customer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
    <div id="dropZone" class="dropzone"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right hidden-mobile" name="add_customer">Add Customer</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div.dropzone', {
    url: "http://localhost/build/assets/php/customer-query.php",                        
    autoProcessQueue: false,
});
$('form.add_customer').submit(function(){
    myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

PHP:

```
// Create folder using name field from form 
$fname = $_POST['name'];
if (!file_exists('../uploads/'.$fname.'/')) {
    mkdir('../uploads/'.$fname.'/', 0777, true);
}

// Upload files to respected folder
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '../uploads/'.$fname.'/';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                 
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

Comment: Remove ../ from $storeFolder and try again.

Comment: after removing "../" now it is not uploading files. with "../" it is uploading files in "uploads" not in "$fname".